# Image links in a list have weird positioning

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Currently without adding image links to the icons they looks like this:

[image]

and my code for that looks like this:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
           <ul style="padding-left:10px;" class="nav navbar-nav"> <
              <li><img src="img/FB.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Facebook"  width="52px" ></li>    
              <li><img src="img/TW.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Twitter"  width="52px" > </li>
              <li><img src="img/PI.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Pinterest"  width="52px" ></li>
           </ul>
```

However once I start to change one of the icons to a image link it becomes like this

[image]

and the code for it is:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
           <ul style="padding-left:10px;" class="nav navbar-nav"> <!-- Content on the left side of the navigation bar  -->
              <li><a href="http://facebook.com"><img src="img/FB.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Facebook" border="0"  width="52px" ></a></li>  
              <li><img src="img/TW.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Twitter"  width="52px" > </li>
              <li><img src="img/PI.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Pinterest"  width="52px" ></li>
           </ul>
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: please provide a fiddle, and include your css

Comment: You should include your CSS and specify which link you have changed, although I think we can safely assume that it is the Facebook image.  I would be quite certain that your issue will be fixed by something like `ul li a { padding-top: 0 ; }` but that's a guess without any actual CSS or a fiddle.

Comment: @user3459426 you can solve this by vertical-alignment:bottom may this will work

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has it's own properties, hence you need to replace them.

```
.nav > li > a { 
     padding-top: 0px !important; 
}
```